# Is there a difference between global require and local require within a function

Tags: function, module, lua, package, require

AFAIK, once the module has been loaded, lua caches the result into package.loaded[modName]. Does this statement hold true irrespective of where we are doing require "module"?

Following example:

In the below example, `script1` just loads the module.lua once so any other usage just fetches the content from package.loaded, whereas `script2` requires it twice. In the second case we are loading the module within the function scope, does that mean lua doesn't cache the result of `require "module"` as to what it does in the first case?

module.lua

```
local Table = {}
local function print_func(message):
    print(message)
end

Table.print_func = print_func

return Table
```

script1.lua

```
local table = require "module"
local function perform()
    table.print_func("PERFORM")
end

local function work()
    table.print_func("WORK")
end
```

script2.lua

```
local function do()
    local table = require "module"
    table.print_func("DO")
end

local function work()
    local table = require "module"
    table.print_func("WORK")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, other than the result will be discarded in the case of a function, but since the Lua engine will cache the result of "require", when "require" is called next time for the same file, the cached value will be returned. It's an additional table lookup in the latter case and is one of the reasons why global "require" is generally preferred.